# Minimizing gives TypeError: bound1Expr() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

When calling the function optimization() defined as

```
def optimization():
    bound1 = {
            'type': 'eq',
            'fun': bound1Expr}
    bound2 = {
            'type': 'eq',
            'fun': bound2Expr}
    optimizeResult = minimize(
                    toOptimize,
                    (0,0,0),
                    method = "SLSQP",
                    options = {'disp': False},
                    constraints = (
                            bound1,
                            bound2
                            )
                        )
    return optimizeResult.x

def bound1Expr(x,y,z):
    return x + y + z -1
    
def bound2Expr(x,y,z):
    return x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 10

def toOptimize(x,y,z):
    return (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)**0.5
```

I get the error

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 313, in <listcomp>
        for c in cons['eq']]))
    
TypeError: bound1Expr() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

I looked at all the sources I could find with the same error, but still I don't know what to do. Often the error occurs related to the *Self* variable, but I am not dealing with classes here. And even when *Self* is implicitly added to the lambda functions, I wouldn't know why that's a problem when I don't use it anyway.

Comment: Read carefully what `minimize` says about arguments the objective function and the constraint functions. Read the docs, not someone else's problem on the web.

Comment: I read the docs carefully, yet I am still puzzled. Similar questions got a lot of answers, so I assumed it wasn't against the (informal) guidelines of stackoverflow to post a question like this.

Comment: Minimize is passing the variable `x` and the `(args,)` variable.  Replace the `lambda` with a function definition that lets you include diagnostic print statements.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I editted my problem to make it clearer and put some print statements in both bound1Expr, bound2Expr and toOptimize. Yet none of them was sadly printed.

Comment: `minimize` is passing a 3 element array like your start value (np.array([0,0,0])).  That's one variable, not 3..  Try `def bound1Expr(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code modified to take one argument, not 3.  I also changed `^` to `**` power.

```
In [105]: def optimization():
     ...:     bound1 = {
     ...:             'type': 'eq',
     ...:             'fun': bound1Expr}
     ...:     bound2 = {
     ...:             'type': 'eq',
     ...:             'fun': bound2Expr}
     ...:     optimizeResult = minimize(
     ...:                     toOptimize,
     ...:                     (0,0,0),
     ...:                     method = "SLSQP",
     ...:                     options = {'disp': False},
     ...:                     constraints = (
     ...:                             bound1,
     ...:                             bound2
     ...:                             )
     ...:                         )
     ...:     return optimizeResult.x
     ...: 
     ...: def bound1Expr(xyz):
     ...:     x,y,z=xyz
     ...:     return x + y + z -1
     ...: 
     ...: def bound2Expr(xyz):
     ...:     x,y,z=xyz
     ...:     return x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 10
     ...: 
     ...: def toOptimize(*args):
     ...:     print('args',args)
     ...:     x,y,z=args[0]
     ...:     return (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5
     ...: 
In [106]: optimization()
args (array([0., 0., 0.]),)
args (array([1.49011612e-08, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]),)
args (array([0.00000000e+00, 1.49011612e-08, 0.00000000e+00]),)
args (array([0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.49011612e-08]),)
Out[106]: array([0., 0., 0.])
```

As `toOptimize` shows, `minimize` passes one value, an array as argument (it would pass more if you provided `args` parameter).  That array has 3 elements, corresponding to the initial value array (tuple).

Getting the function definitions right is often a problem when using these `scipy` functions.  Users ignore, or don't understand the documented definition

```
fun : callable
    The objective function to be minimized.

        ``fun(x, *args) -> float``

    where ``x`` is an 1-D array with shape (n,) and ``args``
    is a tuple of the fixed parameters needed to completely
```

My first comment was responding to your final paragraph about looking at "sources".  Looks like you searched the web for errors about missing or required positional arguments. That's a rather general problem.  Yes, often it occurs when people don't account for the `self` argument of class methods. But that's not the case here, and thus the web search is not productive.

Too often (new) users turn to web (or SO) searches, when they should first check the documentation.  There is a place for web searches (e.g. unique error or very current buggy releases), but for basic usage problems like this you should first make sure you understand how to correctly use the function.